Suppress Jupyter Notebook warning messages in output
I am using papermill and nbconvert to generate HTML files out of my jupyter notebooks.
I recently moved onto a new container (RHEL 8 linux). In this new infra, I continuously get a warning message in every cell, big and pink and ugly:
WARNING:monitoring_extension:Issue posting to monitoring service: Can't identify the notebook path.

I have tried to suppress the warning using libraries 'warnings' and 'shutup' and 'IPython.core.display' -> clear_output. Nothing works! This warning cannot be suppressed!
Anyone have any advice? It seems to only occur with nbconvert, if I run the notebook normally, no warning.
papermill==2.5.0
jupyter==1.0.0
Ran notebook, got HTML output, full of pink warning text.
Tried:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.warn_explicit = warnings.warn = lambda *_, **__: None

Tried:
shutup.please()
Tried:
clear_output(wait=False) at the end of every cell.

"It seems to only occur with nbconvert," " in every cell, big and pink and ugly". In this case an image is warranted. It sounds like you are describing stderr channel, but papermill adds red text, too, and so it would be nice to be sure. I'm not familiar with this warning. There's at least two other approaches I can think of besides what you've tried. You may be able to add a post-processor or add code to the top of your notebook to add a display hook. The thing is that it without a minimal reproducible example, it is hard to test. You'd need to share the commands that make it happen. ...

 Is it possible to make a throw away notebook and have it happen and share the actual file in the most nascent state you can get it? Like an .ipynb file with the warnings of this type that you can make a Github gist with and share, along with all the commands you used to make it?

I can't upload images due to a firewall, but here's the HTML code generated:   
WARNING:monitoring_extension:Issue posting to monitoring service: Can't identify the notebook path.


Re: minimal example, I am not sure I am able, as I suspect the problem is caused by the home dir being mounted in an unusual way in the new container, which is out of my control alas. If anyone has any more suggestions on a possible cause for the warning or how to suppress it I am happy to try.

Any chance re-channeling it, see here(I think), could help you suppress it?

Thank you for the comments, @Wayne , they helped me find the solution below.

Here's an idea to treat the symptom. (Treating the cause would be best unless you are happy other wise? jupyter==1.0.0 looks wrong to me or at least not providing much information. So if you wanted to consider that direction, how did you install Jupyter?) I wish I could post this code block below as a comment, but I need formatting.
Please try posting this at the top of your notebook to be run.
import sys
from IPython import get_ipython

class WarningFilter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = self

    def write(self, output):
        if "WARNING:monitoring_extension:Issue posting to monitoring service: Can't identify the notebook path." not in output:
            self.old_stderr.write(output)

    def flush(self):
        self.old_stderr.flush()

# Install the custom stderr handler
WarningFilter()

# Ensure the filter is used in all new cells
ip = get_ipython()
if ip is not None:
    ip.events.register('pre_run_cell', lambda: WarningFilter())

Sadly, I cannot test. But it may help address it by filtering out that message from stderr. If it even seems to do anything it may be on the right track for ultimately filtering it.

I managed to hide the error messages by inserting the following CSS into the page:
.jp-RenderedText[data-mime-type='application/vnd.jupyter.stderr'] {
   display: none;
   visibility: hidden;
}

Obviously, this treats the symptom and not the root, alas.
